# Get the value of $p$ for no solution in equation of first grade

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

For what value of $p$ the equation not have solutions ?

$\frac{2-x}{x+4} = p$

This can be lineal,

$2-x = px + 4p$

Well, as equation of first grade:

$px + 4p +x -2 = 0$

It not have solutions when given an equation $ax + b = 0$, $a = 0$, $b \neq 0$, so will not have solutions.

I think that in this case $ax$ is represented by $px + 4p$, and $b$ is represented by $x-2$.

so, px + 4p = 0, but from here, I no longer understand what to do.

Comment: `in this case ax is represented by px+4p, and ...` No, you need to collect the terms in $\,x\,$ which are $\,px+x=(p+1)x\,$, and then the terms that do not contain $\,x\,$ which are $\,4p-2\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite as:
$$
\underbrace{(p + 1)}_{\textsf{Must be } 0}x + \underbrace{(4p - 2)}_{\textsf{Must not be } 0} = 0
$$
which forces $p = -1$.

Comment: @AndrewLi If both were zero then the equation would be trivially true for any $x$.

Comment: @Dave Oh, I read the question wrong. My bad.

Comment: Perfect and clear, thanks